# How to configure proxy settings for one job (using nuget) in TeamCity

Tags: .net, proxy, msbuild, nuget, teamcity

I have one job in teamcity which is using MSBuild:

```
MSBuild
Build file: build.xml
Targets: Package
```

I know it's possible to configure proxy settings for the whole teamcity server but I just want to configure proxy settings inside this job. So only this job can use them.

This job is using NuGet to get packages from the internet. Which needs to go through a proxy.

I have a first buildstep in CMD

```
tools\Nuget\nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=http://xxx:8080 -ConfigFile .nuget\Nuget.config
tools\Nuget\nuget.exe config -set https_proxy=http:xxx:8080 -ConfigFile .nuget\Nuget.config
tools\Nuget\nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.user=xxx -ConfigFile .nuget\Nuget.config
tools\Nuget\nuget.exe config -set https_proxy.user=xxx -ConfigFile .nuget\Nuget.config
tools\Nuget\nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.password=xxx -ConfigFile .nuget\Nuget.config
tools\Nuget\nuget.exe config -set https_proxy.password=xxx -ConfigFile .nuget\Nuget.config
```

The configuration is written to the `NuGet.Config`. The sln is pointing to this config. But still I got the following error:

```
[Exec] EXEC (502) Bad Gateway.
Exec] E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\xx\build.xml(26, 5): error MSB3073: The command "tools\Nuget\nuget.exe restore myprojectname.sln"
```

Answer (score 0):

You thought about using something like nexus, which is free to manage your repositories?

Then you can have lots of proxied repos and link them all to a virtual repo, and can be the single source you use for all builds.

https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss
https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-manage-repo.html